Having difficulty sorting Snowflake data that contains numeric and non-numeric data
I have a query in Snowflake where I am returning both numeric and varchar values and am struggling with getting the sort to work correctly.
For context, this column is calculated by dividing two existing columns' values and will display numeric unless something in the calculation is invalid. For instance, if the calculation tries to divide by zero, the cell will display an error message indicating this. However, if the calculation is valid, a numeric value will display.
I am having difficulty handling the sorting of this data.
This is what I have so far, but it is returning the varchar values in both the beginning and the end of the sorted list. However, I would only like these varchar values to display at the beginning of the list.
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY 
 CASE 
     WHEN ISNUMERIC("myfield") = 0 THEN 0 
     ELSE 1 
 END,
 CASE 
     WHEN ISNUMERIC("myfield") = 0 THEN "myfield"
     ELSE NULL
 END,
 TRY_CAST("myfield" AS FLOAT)


Sorting by numbers first, then by myfield value:
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY TRY_CAST("myfield" AS FLOAT), "myfield";

Output:


If text values(non-castable to float) should be at the begining then NULLS FIRST can be used:
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY TRY_CAST("myfield" AS FLOAT) NULLS FIRST, "myfield";


Great answer!!!
